# PHP, grab meta tag data

Tags: php, html

Anyone know how you grab data from a HTML meta tag with PHP?

[live example](http://hemsidavisa.site90.net/PHP/index2.php)

I want it to render the meta title and not the file title. Look at the orange text.

Comment: Stack Overflow should not be your first stop when researching something unless you're here to actually use the search functionality.

Comment: nah there is no similarity with it.  this is a straightforward question with a straightforward answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
```

this will only return meta tags that have named values though

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

go here for examples of usage

Comment: could you be more specific, like this

Comment: More specific? What else do you want?

Comment: I tried the following code, it doesn't render anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: read the link for more information... ps go to the php.net/manual for 90% of your php needs